# I have just downloaded Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS but its failing with error messages when I run sudo apt update

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, update-manager, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I downloaded using WindowStore. I searched for Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS and used that to get and install.

I have just downloaded Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS  but its failing with error messages when I run sudo apt update
My windows is

```
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise
OS Version:                10.0.19044 N/A Build 19044
```

I am running WSL 2

```
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* docker-desktop-data    Running         2
  Ubuntu20.04LTS         Running         2
  docker-desktop         Running         2
```

```
Installation successful!
To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".
See "man sudo_root" for details.
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.10.60.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 x86_64)


* Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
* Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
* Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage
  System information as of Sat Mar 19 19:26:11 GMT 2022
  System load:  0.25               Processes:             8
  Usage of /:   0.5% of 250.98GB   Users logged in:       0
  Memory usage: 9%                 IPv4 address for eth0: 172.29.53.52
  Swap usage:   0%

1 update can be applied immediately.
To see these additional updates run: apt list --upgradable

The list of available updates is more than a week old.
To check for new updates run: sudo apt update
This message is shown once a day. To disable it please create the
/home/tonycav/.hushlogin file.

tonycav@LAP-8M8NK13:~$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for tonycav:

Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'

Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'

Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'

Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

```
tonycav@LAP-8M8NK13:~$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 36:09:ba:44:25:83 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: dummy0: <BROADCAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 6a:5e:23:15:f5:90 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: tunl0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
5: sit0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
6: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:5d:91:6f:4e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.29.53.52/20 brd 172.29.63.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe91:6f4e/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Permissions

```
tonycav@LAP-8M8NK13:~$ ls -l /etc/resolv.conf

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Mar 19 19:25 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

Host file I commented out all the IPv6

```
# This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file, add the following entry to /etc/wsl.conf:
# [network]
# generateHosts = false
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       LAP-8M8NK13.localdomain LAP-8M8NK13
<feff>

192.168.0.11    host.docker.internal
192.168.0.11    gateway.docker.internal
127.0.0.1       kubernetes.docker.internal

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
#::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
#fe00::0 ip6-localnet
#ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
#ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
#ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: Nope I tried all them. I tried 
 ```
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf > /dev/null
```
It did not fix the issue
Its not a upgarde from an old version

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1398337/edit) to include the complete output of `ip a`. Also clearly describe how you installed Ubuntu: Dual boot? WSL? Microsoft Store? Within a Windows docker container? Something else? If you followed installation instructions, a link would be helpful.

Comment: Something might be down currently. Wait an hour or so, and see if the issue goes away. Also, does `ping ubuntu.com` work?

Comment: Pinging ubuntu.com [185.125.190.20] with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 185.125.190.20: bytes=32 time=213ms TTL=58
Updating my question with more information

Comment: Ok I tried it on my own laptop. it works. But not on my work laptop. I guess there is something on my work laptop that stops the update.